# Refering master page from other solution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 4 different solutions and one solution contains master page. that project name is MainView which has master page. and has  Resources folder that contains home.master  page.

I want to refer this master page in other solution. I'm using Visual studio 2010.

```
 public const string VirtualMasterPagePath = "~/";
 public const string ewmainMasterPageFileLocation ="~/Resources/home.master";
```

i have the above lines of code in master page.

and

```
 protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
  {
     MasterPageFile = clsVirtualPathProvider.ewmainMasterPageFileLocation;
     base.OnPreInit(e);
  }
```

these lines of code i used to refer master page.

Getting **error** like :

```
file "/home.master" does not exists.
```

Please help me out... Thank you..

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/430779

Comment: Is it different projects or different solutions??

Comment: different solutions.